# conditional subseting with square brackets or inside square brackets

Tags: r

I have two vectors p1,p2 they report the same information except p2 is more precise. So I want to pick compare the 2 and pick the value from p2 except if the difference between the 2 vectors is > k. In that case I want the value from p1 to be picked in the final product "pd".

```
k <- 5
p1 <- c(21,43,62,88,119,156,264)
p2 <- c(19,42,62,84,104,156,262)
```

pd should look like:

```
pd <- c(19,42,62,84,119,156,262)
```

I have seen code that specified the selection condition inside the square brackets, but can't figure out how to duplicate it. Something similar to pd <- p2[p1, p1-p2 >5], but not exactly because this obviously doesn't evaluate. p2[p1-p2<5] works to select the positive cases but the 5th case where the condition evaluate to FALSE is skipped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be

```
ifelse(abs(p2-p1) <=k, p2, p1)
#[1]  19  42  62  84 119 156 262
```

Or without using `ifelse`

```
indx <- abs(p1-p2) >k
pd <- p2
pd[indx] <- p1[indx]
pd
#[1]  19  42  62  84 119 156 262
```